# requestvalidationmode causes issue with build script

Tags: .net, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, requestvalidationmode

I added

```
requestvalidationmode=2.0
```

to my page header.

Everything works great.  However when I try and build this on my build server it crashes with this message:

```
errorASPPARSE: Error parsing attribute 'requestvalidationmode': Type 'MYASPFORM' does not have a public property named 'requestvalidationmode'.
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this attribute was introduced in framework 4.0, is your build server building your project with the correct framework?